# Waiting for all the threads to finish before shutting down the Executors

Tags: java, wait, executorservice

Here is my code snippet.

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(ThreadPoolSize);
while(conditionTrue)
{
ClassImplementingRunnable c = new ClassImplementingRunnable();
executor.submit(c);
}
```

Now after this is do

```
executor.shutdown();
```

What i want to achieve here is that i want to wait for all the threads in the threadpool to have finished the execution and then i want to shutdown the executor.

But i guess this is not what is happening here. The main thread seems to be executing shutdown and it just shuts down everything.

Before when my threadpool size was 2, i did the following and it seemed to work.

```
ClassImplementingRunnable c1 = new ClassImplementingRunnable();
executor.submit(c1);
ClassImplementingRunnable c2 = new ClassImplementingRunnable();
executor.submit(c2);
Future f1 = executor.submit(c1);
Future f2 = executor.submit(c2);
while(!f1.done || !f2.done)
{}
executor.submit();
```

How do i do this for a greater number of threads in the threadpool?
Thanks.

Comment: This won't work if you have two threads as both tasks could be performed by the same thread while the other is still busy.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You generally use the following idiom:

```
executor.shutdown();
executor.awaitTermination(Integer.MAX_VALUE, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

- [`shutdown`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdown%28%29) just says that the executor won't accept new jobs.
- [`awaitTermination`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#awaitTermination%28long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29) waits until all the tasks that have already been submitted finish what they are doing (or until the timeout is reached - which won't happen with Integer.MAX_VALUE - you might want to use a lower value).

Comment: what is the MAX_VALUE and SECONDS?

Comment: @Kraken It is the timeout - so it you use `executor.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);` it will wait at most 1 second for example.

Comment: i am not sure how long will it take? So i just put in a large number randomly?

Comment: @Kraken If you want to make sure you wait until everything is done, yes. I have added links to the javadoc. Alternatively, you can use Marko's solution if you don't want to wait more than a certain amount of time.

Comment: but it still wont be as efficient as waiting till all the processes have finished, and ending immediately after that.?

Comment: @Kraken awaitTermination will return as soon as all the threads have finished - it is equivalent to your code with `while(!f1.done || !f2.done) {}`.

Comment: so if i say MAX_VALUE=1000 and the threads finish execution after 10 seconds it waits for only 10 seconds?
Thanks

Answer (score 8):

`shutdown` is a "soft" order and won't abruptly shut down the executor. It will do just what you want: refuse any new tasks, wait for all submitted tasks to complete, and then shut down.

Add `awaitTermination` to your code in order to block until the executor service is shut down.

In the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) there's also this code that covers all the angles:

```
void shutdownAndAwaitTermination(ExecutorService pool) {
   pool.shutdown(); // Disable new tasks from being submitted
   try {
     // Wait a while for existing tasks to terminate
     if (!pool.awaitTermination(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)) {
       pool.shutdownNow(); // Cancel currently executing tasks
       // Wait a while for tasks to respond to being cancelled
       if (!pool.awaitTermination(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
           System.err.println("Pool did not terminate");
     }
   } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
     // (Re-)Cancel if current thread also interrupted
     pool.shutdownNow();
     // Preserve interrupt status
     Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

> What i want to achieve here is that i want to wait for all the threads in the threadpool to have finished the execution and then i want to shutdown the executor.

That is what `executor.shutdown();` does. If you want to shutdown immediately you need to use `shutdownNow()`