# Correct way to submit to and wait for termination of an ExecutorService

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, executorservice

I am learning how to use thread pools in Java using `ExecutorService`, here is an example I am working on:

```
public class Example {
    static class WorkerThread implements Runnable {
        private String command;

        public WorkerThread(String s) {
            this.command = s;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " Start. Command = " + command);
            processCommand();
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " End.");
        }

        private void processCommand() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return this.command;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            Runnable worker = new WorkerThread("" + i);
            executor.execute(worker);
        }
        executor.shutdown();
        executor.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
//        while (!executor.isTerminated()) {
//        }
        System.out.println("Finished all threads");
    }
}
```

**I have two questions:**

1. How should I wait for the termination of an `ExecutorService`, should I use `awaitTermination()` or `isTerminated()` (it has been suggested that the latter is a wrong way to do it)?
2. Are the `Runnable`s correctly added to the executor or should I use `submit()` together with a `Future<T>` callback?

It probably depends on the context, so would you please explain (for both questions) when should I use each of the solutions mentioned.

Comment: You can use both `awaitTermination()` to wait (It can throw an InterruptedException), and then `isTerminated()` in the catch block to check for successful termination. Future<T> callbacks are used when you want to know whether an individual task has been processed yet.

Answer (score 2):

This program is not waiting for the threads to terminate, the JVM is doing the waiting: The output I get is:

```
pool-1-thread-1 Start. Command = 0
pool-1-thread-2 Start. Command = 1
pool-1-thread-3 Start. Command = 2
pool-1-thread-4 Start. Command = 3
pool-1-thread-5 Start. Command = 4
Finished all threads
pool-1-thread-2 End.
pool-1-thread-1 End.
pool-1-thread-4 End.
pool-1-thread-1 Start. Command = 5
pool-1-thread-3 End.
pool-1-thread-2 Start. Command = 7
pool-1-thread-5 End.
pool-1-thread-4 Start. Command = 6
pool-1-thread-5 Start. Command = 9
pool-1-thread-3 Start. Command = 8
pool-1-thread-3 End.
pool-1-thread-5 End.
pool-1-thread-4 End.
pool-1-thread-1 End.
pool-1-thread-2 End.
```

You will notice that `Finished all threads` is not at the bottom. If you want to wait for all the threads to finish, use this:

```
public class Example {
    static class WorkerThread implements Runnable {
        private String command;

        public WorkerThread(String s) {
            this.command = s;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " Start. Command = " + command);
            processCommand();
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " End.");
        }

        private void processCommand() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return this.command;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
        List<Callable<Object>> tasks = new ArrayList<Callable<Object>>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            tasks.add(Executors.callable(new WorkerThread("" + i)));
        }
        executor.invokeAll(tasks);
        System.out.println("Finished all threads");
        // this merely terminates the ExecutorService, otherwise the JVM will never close.
        executor.shutdown();
        executor.awaitTermination(10L, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    }
}
```

You will notice the correct output:

```
pool-1-thread-1 Start. Command = 0
pool-1-thread-5 Start. Command = 4
pool-1-thread-4 Start. Command = 3
pool-1-thread-3 Start. Command = 2
pool-1-thread-2 Start. Command = 1
pool-1-thread-3 End.
pool-1-thread-1 End.
pool-1-thread-5 End.
pool-1-thread-3 Start. Command = 5
pool-1-thread-2 End.
pool-1-thread-4 End.
pool-1-thread-2 Start. Command = 8
pool-1-thread-1 Start. Command = 7
pool-1-thread-5 Start. Command = 6
pool-1-thread-4 Start. Command = 9
pool-1-thread-1 End.
pool-1-thread-4 End.
pool-1-thread-3 End.
pool-1-thread-5 End.
pool-1-thread-2 End.
Finished all threads
```

Answer (score 1):

Couple of ways to achieve it:
(a) Call `awaitTermination(long someTime, TimeUnit ....)` inside `while (!executor.isTerminated())`. 
(b) Store all callable inside Collection object and call `executor.invokeAll(....)`. This is going to wait till all task gets completed by executor service.

Answer (score 1):

> 1.How should I wait for the termination of an ExecutorService, should I use awaitTermination() or isTerminated() (it has been suggested that the latter is a wrong way to do it)?

1. You can use `awaitTermination()` after `shutdown()`
   OR
2. You can use `invokeAll()` on executor service by passing List of Runnable/Callable tasks
   OR
3. You can use `CountDownLatch`

Have a look at related SE questions for more details:

[How to wait for all threads to finish, using ExecutorService?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1250643/how-to-wait-for-all-threads-to-finish-using-executorservice)

[ExecutorService, how to wait for all tasks to finish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3269445/executorservice-how-to-wait-for-all-tasks-to-finish)

[Waiting for all the threads to finish before shutting down the Executors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12193513/waiting-for-all-the-threads-to-finish-before-shutting-down-the-executors)

> 2.Are the Runnables correctly added to the executor or should I use submit() together with a Future callback?

1. If you just want to run the command without waiting for the result, use `Runnable`
2. If you want to check the result of task after execution, use `Callable`

If you use `submit()`, exceptions are hidden in framework and you have to take care of handling the exceptions properly.

Have a look at related SE questions:

[Choose between ExecutorService's submit and ExecutorService's execute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3929342/choose-between-executorservices-submit-and-executorservices-execute)

[difference between executor.submit and executor.execute in this code in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18730290/difference-between-executor-submit-and-executor-execute-in-this-code-in-java)